# How can I put my countdown timer letters below the timer

Tags: javascript

For example: 1 23 3 59
d h m s

how can I do it with my existing code?

my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>      
    <h2 id="countdown"></h2>  
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
CountDownTimer('06/15/2022 07:30 PM', 'countdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
    let end = new Date(dt);
    let _second = 1000;
    let _minute = _second * 60;
    let _hour = _minute * 60;
    let _day = _hour * 24;
    let timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        let now = new Date();
        let distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'The event started!';
            
            return;
        }
        
        let days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        let hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        let minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        let seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds;
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

}
```

I was be able to get it side by side with letters but not below every timer...
BTW, I'm new to JS.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Can you please try to restate it? In particular, what do you mean by "For example: 1 23 3 59 d h m s" and "below every timer." Thanks!

Comment: @RyanO'D Yes, I mean by that that I want the d(which is for days) will be below 1, h(which is for hours) will be below 23 and so on. Thank you!

Comment: You want one by one from top to bottom right ?

Comment: @dineshoz yes from my understanding.

Comment: Look at the posted answer. You meant that ?

Comment: @dineshoz no, only letters. but in the second line below the time, the time should stay as I posted. Thanks!

Comment: comment the expected result

Comment: @dineshoz the timer the letters(in the one line below the timer)

Comment: Expected result : the timer the letters ?

Comment: @dineshoz yes. but not side by side. d below the days. h below the hours and so on.

Comment: Check the solution now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
CountDownTimer('06/15/2022 07:30 PM', 'countdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
    let end = new Date(dt);
    let _second = 1000;
    let _minute = _second * 60;
    let _hour = _minute * 60;
    let _day = _hour * 24;
    let timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        let now = new Date();
        let distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'The event started!';
            
            return;
        }
        
        let days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        let hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        let minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        let seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days+ " ";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + " ";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes+ " ";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds+ " <br/>";
        
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "D ";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "M ";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "H ";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "S ";
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>      
    <h2 id="countdown"></h2>  
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```